# SSL Installation apache not starting

Tags: ssl, putty

When I am installing SSL on a server using PuTTY and start the server it could be given an error like action start failed.

```
[Wed Jun 27 13:22:01.911656 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18745] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. 
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196213 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18832] AH02203: Init: Private key not found 
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196274 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18832] SSL Library Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long 
[Wed Jun 27 13:30:53.196280 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18832] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

Comment: The error message looks clear to me: Private key not found.
Check the certificate setup of the server. Check the private key.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Maybe suggest the OP how to check the setup/how to generate the private keys.

Comment: SSL configurtion involve many steps. Your issue seems to be how the certificate is created. First question could be: How is the certificate created? Name of the certificate and name of private key file. Then, how are they installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** @MrShunz is a reviewer on this site, just like me. Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* does the OP have to do? How? Do you have any additional [Tips or Tricks](/help/how-to-answer)? Please **[edit]** your post to add information before the system deletes this because of low quality...  **:-(**

Comment: Based on the limited information supplied in the question I can only check the error mesasge. That message is clear and shows that it is a private key issue. So, the first step is to supply WHERE the certificate is comming from, is it a correct one etc. My suggestion is a first hint in where to start the research. More excact steps cannot be given, based on the supplied info.